# How to access X-Nucleo-NFC05A1 expansion board within Arm MBED?

Tags: arm, nfc, mbed

First of all I am very new to application development with ST-Electronic device shields.

I have following devices with me,

- X-NUCLEO-NFC05A1
- NFC expansion shield Nucleo 64 : F401RE board.

I was doing some samples with ARM Mbed online compiler. 
I want to access external NFC tag's content via NFC05A1 expansion board in ARM Mbed. However, I was not able to find a correct library for NFC05A1 expansion board in ARM Mbed. But, I found a sample and a library for different version of NFC shield : https://os.mbed.com/components/X-NUCLEO-NFC01A1/ and this is not compatible with the NFC05A1.

I was wondering whether there is a library which I can use in ARM Mbed to access NFC functionality in X-NUCLEO-NFC05A1 board.

Note: I found a following CUBE sample for this expansion board but, I do not think this can be used in ARM Mbed as a library.
https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcu-mpu-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-expansion-packages/x-cube-nfc5.html